# using Java-Metro, from server side, how to get ssl client certificate details?

Tags: java, ssl, glassfish-3, java-metro-framework

i am using Java Metro framework for publishing web services, 
i configure the ssl handshake to require a ssl certificate from client,
how can i catch the ssl client certificate details in my server code ? 
Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution of my question,

taking the CalculatorWS as example, you have to write the following to get certificate details:

```
@WebService()
public class CalculatorWS {

   // NEW
   private WebServiceContext wsCtx;
   @Resource
   private void setWSContext(WebServiceContext wsCtx) {
       this.wsCtx = wsCtx;
   }
   // END NEW

   public CalculatorWS() {}

   @WebMethod(operationName = "add", action="add")
   public int add(@WebParam(name = "i") int i, @WebParam(name = "j") int j) {
      // NEW
      if (this.wsCtx != null) {
         MessageContext msgCtx = this.wsCtx.getMessageContext();
         HttpServletRequest httpSR = (HttpServletRequest)msgCtx.get(MessageContext.SERVLET_REQUEST );
         X509Certificate[] x509Cert = (X509Certificate[])httpSR.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate");
      }
      // END NEW
  ...
```